# Generic InBetween Function

Tags: c#, generics

I am tired of writing `x > min && x < max` so i wawnt to write a simple function but I am not sure if I am doing it right... actually I am not cuz I get an error:

```
    bool inBetween<T>(T x, T min, T max) where T:IComparable
    {
        return (x > min && x < max);
    }
```

errors:

```
Operator '>' cannot be applied to operands of type 'T' and 'T'
Operator '<' cannot be applied to operands of type 'T' and 'T'
```

may I have a bad understanding of the `where` part in the function declaring

note: for those who are going to tell me that I will be writing more code than before... think on readability =)
any help will be appreciated

**EDIT**

deleted cuz it was resolved =)

**ANOTHER EDIT**

so after some headache I came out with this (ummm) thing following @Jay Idea of extreme readability:

```
public static class test
{
    public static comparision Between<T>(this T a,T b) where T : IComparable
    {
        var ttt = new comparision();
        ttt.init(a);
        ttt.result = a.CompareTo(b) > 0;
        return ttt;
    }

    public static bool And<T>(this comparision state, T c) where T : IComparable
    {
        return state.a.CompareTo(c) < 0 && state.result;
    }

    public class comparision
    {
        public IComparable a;
        public bool result;          
        public void init<T>(T ia) where T : IComparable
        {
            a = ia;
        }

    }
}
```

now you can compare anything with extreme readability =)

what do you think.. I am no performance guru so any tweaks are welcome

Comment: To your EDIT: extension methods must be static and put in a static class.

Comment: oh!!!! yes thats right... my bad =)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[IComparable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icomparable.aspx) means the object implements a CompareTo method. Use

```
public static bool InBetween<T>(this T x, T min, T max) where T:IComparable<T>
{
    return x.CompareTo(min) > 0 && x.CompareTo(max) < 0;
}
```

Comment: @Sparkie could you point me to a resource to understand your change?

Comment: When you use the non-generic `IComparable`, it has a `.CompareTo()` method which expects an `object`. So in when min or max are passed to it, they need to be objects. (They may be structs for instance, which are not objects, they're valuetypes). If they are structs, they are **boxed**, which basically creates an object to reference the struct, but this can cost over 10% more in some situations, resulting in slower code (particularly noticeable when used on collections).

Comment: In the case of the generic `IComparable<T>`, the `CompareTo()` method expects a T, which is what min and max already are constrained to. No boxing is needed in that case.

Comment: @Sparkie didn't realize I was Constraining to the wrong interface. Thought they were the same for some reason. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the `.CompareTo` method of your variable and check for < and > 0. (This is why you've constrained T to IComparable).

```
return (x.CompareTo(min) > 0 && x.CompareTo(max) < 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
return x.CompareTo(min) > 0 && x.CompareTo(max) < 0;
```

If you're going for maximum readability, you could use an extension method on `IComparable<T>`, and create a syntax like:

```
return 5.IsBetween(10).and(20);
```

or

```
return 5.IsBetween(10.and(20));
```

Here is an implementation for the second example:

```
public interface IRange<T>
{
    bool ContainsInclusive(T value);
    bool ContainsExclusive(T value);
}

public class ComparableRange<T> : IRange<T> where T : IComparable<T>
{
    T min;
    T max;

    public ComparableRange(T min, T max)
    {
        this.min = min;
        this.max = max;
    }

    public bool ContainsInclusive(T value)
    {
        return value.CompareTo(min) >= 0 && value.CompareTo(max) <= 0;
    }

    public bool ContainsExclusive(T value)
    {
        return value.CompareTo(min) > 0 && value.CompareTo(max) < 0;
    }
}

public static class ComparableExtensions
{
    public static IRange<T> and<T>(this T min, T max) where T : IComparable<T>
    {
        return new ComparableRange<T>(min, max);
    }

    public static bool IsBetween<T>(this T value, IRange<T> range) where T : IComparable<T>
    {
        return range.ContainsExclusive(value);
    }
}
```

Comment: still waiting for that golden implementation

Comment: @Yuriy @Luiscencio I added an update with an example implementation. This is an exercise; not a recommendation. You could do the same thing with a tuple, instead of a range, but you'd be putting the actual comparison logic in the extension method.

Answer (score 0):

Use [IComparable.CompareTo()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icomparable.compareto.aspx):

a.CompareTo(b) > 0    <=>  a>b

a.CompareTo(b) = 0    <=>  a=b

a.CompareTo(b) < 0    <=>  a<b

```
public bool InBetween<T>(T x, T min, T max) where T:IComparable
{
    return x.CompareTo(min) * x.CompareTo(max) < 0;
}
```

Comment: Clever choice of multiplication, even if it's not the most transparent solution.

Comment: Multiplication is not a clever choice. Consider someone else use something like this: `bool result = InBetween(5,10,4);`, which returns `true`. So that you need to add a check to make sure `max` is greater than `min`, if not then `return false`, which makes the method more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding a constraint that T is an IComparable, and then using CompareTo instead of < and >.

But this probably won't let you send all the value types you may want to. In that case, just create the overloads you need, without generics.